# Multilevel logistic regression for 3 by 3 factorial design? Sparse matrix problem

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis

For the sake of example, let’s say this is a costumer research study.

I have a binary outcome (x) that is either making a purchase or not making it.

I have three independent variables: store decoration (A), interaction with customer (B), price (C).

Each variable has three levels:

- store decoration: high level decoration, medium level decoration, no     decoration
- interaction with customer: friendly interaction, minimal interaction, no interaction
- price: high price, medium price, low       price

This gives me a total of 27 conditions.

I have run the study on one participant using a virtual simulation, with a total of 27 trials (one trial per condition).

These are the results (I am using r):

```
A <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
B <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2)
C <- c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2)
x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)
data <- data.frame(A, B, C, x)
```

What is the best way to analyze this data?

Should I use a multilevel logistic regression since the outcome is binary? I am concerned that the data is too sparse.

How to get more data? If I had more than one participant, could I collate them in the matrix? Or is the right way to go to run more trials? The problem is that with a matrix so sparse I am afraid I would have to run a ton of trials.